# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. dataGridOrderAdmin было null

Tags: c#, ado.net, datagrid

Пытаюсь заполнить dataGrid данной строкой кода:

```
dataGridOrderAdmin.ItemsSource = Entities.GetContext().Order.ToList();
```

GetContext это:

```
public static Entities _context;

public static Entities GetContext()
{
    if (_context == null)
        _context = new Entities();

    return _context;
}
```

Выдает данную ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам ведь прямым текстом сказано, что `dataGridOrderAdmin` у вас NULL. Вот и копайте в эту сторону, почему он у вас вдруг NULL, может до `InitializeComponent()` написали код, может еще что, нам от куда это знать?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо я похоже немного действительно умственно не полноценный написал до InitializeComponent() и не замечал такую мелочь